# WPF Binding to ObservableCollection - only update collection when row is complete

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a basic `DataGrid` that I'm using to create a list of enemies for a game project I've been playing around with:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="EnemyGrid" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="8.273,3.781" Height="162" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Name"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Level, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Level"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Role, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Role"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `DataGrid` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` that is read in from a `json` file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Enemy> EnemyList;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var data = JsonHelpers.ReadFile<Enemy>("Enemy.json");
        EnemyList = data["Enemy"];
        EnemyGrid.DataContext = EnemyList;
     }
}
```

In case it matters, the ReadFile method uses `JSON.Net`:

```
public static Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<T>> ReadFile<T>(this string fileName)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(dataPath + fileName);                        

    Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<T>> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<T>>>(text);

    return data;
}
```

**Side note:** the return type is `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<T>>` because I need to maintain the table declaration in the `json` file. If I can keep the format as `"TableName" : [{Table}]` without this then I'd appreciate the input.

In short, the problem I'm having is related to when the `DataGrid` posts an update. Per some related questions, I've created an empty constructor for the `Enemy` class. As soon as I type the first character in the `Name` field on `EnemyGrid`, the collection tries to update and I get default values for most of the properties on the `Enemy` class.

Also note that although I've set `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` on the columns, the collection continues to update as soon as I've started typing. Ideally, I would like for the object to be created once I've finished adding values in the `row`, but the update happens once a `cell` is edited.

*How can I make the `DataGrid` wait to perform this update so that I have all of my required parameters when the object is created?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a direct way to do what you're trying to do. If your only option is to edit within a data grid, you may need to create an `EnemyViewModel` for your data that has the same properties as your `Enemy`, except every property is nullable.

So, if your `Enemy` looks like this:

```
public class Enemy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

...your `EnemyViewModel` would look like this:

```
public class EnemyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public Role? Role { get; set; }
}
```

This way, the default values for everything across the row of a table will be `null`, which will appear blank/unfilled to the user.

A simple LINQ query will allow you to convert the enemies you read in from your JSON to an `ObservableCollection<EnemyViewModel>`:

```
EnemyGrid.DataContext =
    new ObservableCollection<EnemyViewModel>(
        enemies.Select(x => new EnemyViewModel { Name = x.Name, Level = x.Level, Role = x.Role }));
```

The problem, though, is that unfilled values will not get a red box around them. So, if you have some sort of "Save" or "Submit" button, you will need to check your view model items for blank values and put up a warning for the user to fix that.

---

If you don't absolutely need to edit within the data grid, you could use it only for displaying your data and create a small form with each field getting its own label and TextBox (or whatever input widget makes the most sense). When the user submits this, you would then add it to your observable collection, and the table would update automatically. This would be a little more work, but will give you a lot more control over the user interface and could result in a better user experience.